# c++ - function requires c style array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I need to use some static c-libraries in my c++ code. 
There I have a lot of functions which look like this (here I use a very simple example in this library to create a rotation matrix about the z-axis with the angel alpha):

```
void Rz(double alpha, double r[3][3])
```

In the end, r should be the final matrix.
I tried to call the function like this:

```
double alpha = 1.234;
double R[3][3] = {}; 
iauRz(alpha, R);
for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i){
    cout  << "    "  << R[i][0] << " " << R[i][1] << " "  << R[i][2] << "\n";
}
```

and I hoped to display the rotation matrix, but this doesn't work. My result is:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Is there a mistake how I call the function? I'm not familiar with this c-style arrays...

EDIT: The library offers some very complex functions, the rotation about the z-axis was just a example. This means it is no possibility to use a more c++ style library. 
EDIT 2: indices changed

Comment: Indices are 0 based in c++. These arrays' elements are at index 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: You access memory out of bounds of your array: `R[i][3]`

Comment: Change `R[i][1] << " " << R[i][2] << " "  << R[i][3] << "\n";` to `R[i][0] << " " << R[i][1] << " "  << R[i][2] << "\n";`

Comment: Your way of calling of the library function is OK based on the stated description of the function. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using indices starting from 1. Indices start from 0 in C/C++

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i){
    cout  << "    "  << R[i][0] << " " << R[i][1] << " "  << R[i][2] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks, this was a small stupid mistake. I fixed it but it still doesn't change the value of R

Comment: I see you're declaring `R` without any assignment, then you pass it to `iauRz(alpha, R);`. Is `iauRz` supposed to change the value of `R`? Did you write that function (then, can you post the function definition?) or it comes from an external library (then which one?) ?

Answer (score 0):

Indices are zero based in almost every language and this has a reason: R[i] in C++ (and C) can also be written as

```
*(R + i * sizeof(datatype))
```

which means "take the memory address of R increased i times by the size of the datatype of the array and get the value at that address", so it makes perfect sense to have the first object of the array at R[0], because this is the memory address of R plus 0 bytes, so the first element